# CSS - Display text next to icon inside the button on the :hover effect

Tags: css, reactjs, button, transition

I am having a little problem with displaying the text inside the button on the `:hover` effect. I want to have an effect where user will hover of the button and the text appears.
I managed to make it work, but the text is to close to the icon itself, and when I add the `margin` I get bad proportion of the box.

Here is the code:

#### CSS

```
.favourite-btn {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.favourite-btn__text {
  max-width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  transition: max-width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
.favourite-btn:hover .favourite-btn__text {
  max-width: 15rem;
}
```

#### JSX

```
<button className="favourite-btn rounded-md">
  <AiOutlineHeart className="text-2xl favourite-btn__icon" />
  <span className="favourite-btn__text">Add to favourites</span>
</button>
```

I am also using `TailwindCSS` but that is not important in this case I think. What can I do to fix this?

If you want to test the button I made a sandbox for it. Here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-forest-k5cr50?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

```
.favourite-btn {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.favourite-btn__text {
  max-width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  //margin-left: 0.5rem // remove this line
  transition: max-width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: margin-left 0.3s ease-in-out; // also add animation to margin
}
.favourite-btn:hover .favourite-btn__text {
  margin-left: 0.5rem; // add margin to the text on hover
  max-width: 15rem;
}
```

Comment: this will not work. When you stop hovering you will get an instant lost of margin which will result in weird transition. Tried this already, but thank you!